# Error when using tfd.TransformedDistribution in TF 2.1.0, TFP 0.9.0: "AttributeError: Tensor.name is meaningless when eager execution is enabled."

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to use tfd.TransformedDistribution to apply a chain of bijectors to modify a bivariate Gaussian distribution, and I'm getting the error noted above ("AttributeError: Tensor.name is meaningless when eager execution is enabled.").  I'm using using TensorFlow 2.0 (Python) and TensorFlow Probability 0.9.0 in a Jupyter Notebook hosted in a Chrome browser, version 94.0.4606.61.  The call that appears to provoke the error is this:

x_dist = tfd.TransformedDistribution(z, chain_of_bijectors)

Some of the chained bijectors have been subclassed using naming conventions similar to what is shown below, but the error happens even when I use a single bijector (i.e., even one derived directly from TensorFlow's library of bijectors).  The bijectors appear to work normally (with no errors) when used in a scrutinized sequence that resembles the chain.

Example code snippet of a typical subclassed bijector:

```
class MyBijector(tfb.Bijector):

    def __init__(self, validate_args=False, name='my_bijector'):
        super(MyBijector, self).__init__(
            validate_args=validate_args, 
            forward_min_event_ndims=0, 
            name=name
        )
```

To resolve the error, I have tried different variations of the subclass names (for the two init's ), and removing the names altogether.  (The fact that the same error occurs even when a single, non-subclassed bijector is used in the function call seems to suggest the issue is not really with the names of the bijectors). I also tried disabling eager execution (which seems unnecessary).  When eager execution was disabled, the code ran normally until the same call, and then it produced a different error related to the chain of bijectors:  "ValueError: 'chain_of_[...string of mostly bijector names omitted here...]/forward/add:0' is not a valid scope name".

Can anyone explain the cause of the AttributeError and how to fix it?  If eager execution must be disabled to run this code, how can I fix the ValueError?  Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help to answer you question. A well asked question makes it much more likely to get an answer that resolves your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.  I figured out the problem:  In the function call listed above ("x_dist = tfd.TransformedDistribution(z, chain_of_bijectors)"), z was a sample from an underlying distribution, rather than the distribution itself, causing the error.  The error went away once I passed z as an actual distribution object, rather than as a sample from such an object.